# Replace cells in spreadsheet with cells from different spreadsheet in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with phone numbers.

```
347-286-3341
347-286-3342
347-286-3343
347-286-3344
347-286-3345
```

etc...

I have another spreadsheet with phone numbers and corresponding names.

```
347-286-3342    Jonson
347-286-3344    Smith
347-286-3345    Walken
```

How I can replace phone numbers in the first spreadsheet with corresponding names from the second?

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, just use the VLOOKUP formula. Try following the steps below:

1. Suppose your phone numbers in Sheet 1 start from A1, then enter the following formula in B1

=VLOOKUP(A1,'[Book2]Sheet1'!$A:$B,2,0)

2. After entering the formula you will get the Names, then simply copy column B, and paste special values.
3. Replace column A with column B